# Web View Opening in the Browser

Tags: android

I know this question asked many times. But that is not solving my problem. Pls check in my  mainactivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        this.webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);



        webView.loadUrl("http://doopme.co.in/recharge/b2b/app");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.webView.canGoBack()) {
            this.webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

I am not getting any error with the following code but when when i click on it its opening the browser. After some google search, i found that i need to change this line to `webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);` to `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientImpl(this));` but I am getting an error.

Comment: in my emulator its opening in WEBVIEW browser tester

Comment: Unless you have your own class named `WebViewClientImpl`, you probably want just `WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient();` instead.

Comment: I tried but still opening in the browser...

Comment: Add this: ` webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(this)); ` Remove: `WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);`

Comment: what kine of error u are getting? i have check it is perfectly works fine

Comment: I got my solution from  webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);